# Telegram CLI unread messages

Tags: raspberry-pi, telegram

I want to display **unread messages** with telegram cli running on my raspberry pi, and save them to some file which will be processed later with php, and displayed on a small TFT screen.

I think it may be possible with *get_dialog_list ()* but I can't find a way to make it work.

Any help/advice is welcome! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you choose php as a laguage to write your customized client or just pull messages from Telegram, you need to connect to the tg client and then send or receive messages.
You can easily wirte a Bash script and use it inside your php code.

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$(date)
from=$1
subject=$2
body=$3
tgpath=/home/telpath/tg
LOGFILE="/home/logpath/tglog.log"
cd ${tgpath}
${tgpath}/telegram -k ${tgpath}/tg-server.pub -W <<EOF
msg $to $subject
safe_quit
EOF
echo "$now Recipient=$from " >> ${LOGFILE}
echo "Finished" >> ${LOGFILE}
```

So we will have:

```
<?php
while (TRUE) {
   $output = shell_exec('tg.sh', '#user');
   echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
}    
?>
```

You can easily iterate over your bash script (tg.sh) to pull messages from any contact.
Note that these codes are trivial like a sudo code and needs more development.